# SSH Tunnel to access EC2 Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, ssh, amazon-ec2, cloudera, ssh-tunnel

Background :

1. I have installl 3 Node Cloudera Hadoop Cluster on EC2 Instance which is workin as expected.
2. Client Program on my windows machine to load data from my machine to HDFS.

Details :

My client program has developed in Java which reads data from the windows local disk and write it to HDFS.

For this I am trying to create SSH Tunnel through Putty and than I am trying to login with my windows username to the remote EC2 Instance Which is not working. I am able to login with the unix username. I wanted to understand is this correct behavior?

I don't know I have created tunnel correctly or not but after that when I try to run my client program it gives me below error :

My client program has developed in Java which reads data from the windows local disk and write it to HDFS. When I am trying to run my programs It is givin me below error.

```
PriviledgedActionException as:ubuntu (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: File /user/ubuntu/features.json could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.

6:32:45.711 PM     INFO     org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server     

IPC Server handler 13 on 8020, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 108.161.91.186:54097: error: java.io.IOException: File /user/ubuntu/features.json could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
java.io.IOException: File /user/ubuntu/features.json could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:44954)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1695)
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Are the data nodes alive, i.e. started? Can you access HDFS via the web interface on those nodes?

Comment: Yes, all the datanodes are working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your hdfs cluster health with `hdfs fsck / -delete`, then you can rebalance your datanodes.